# cloning vm using powershell - cloning is stuck on 35%

Tags: powershell, vmware-esxi

I have an issue that started lately - I have a script that clone a VM using PowerShell:

```
New-VM -Name $VM_Name -VM $cloneMe -VMHost $ESXi -Datastore $ds -Location $FoldertoCloneto -RunAsync
```

lately, when I use this command the cloning is stuck on 35% and fails after a while on timeout.

If I clone the same VM manually it clones without any issues.

Do you have an idea of what can I change?, or where should I look in the logs to understand why it gets stuck so I'll be able to fix this issue?

thanks in advance :)